# How can i make an app that will work for desktop windows and IOS with phonegap?

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I want to be able to access folders and files via my app, the problem is, when i want to access files on the desktop, i have to run it from a server or at least to emulate one using a program like xampp.
I know PhoneGap has it's own API to access files, but i need to make the app work on desktop too, and i don't mind it to be as normal offline website ( via index.html, not an exe ), but i still need to solve the security issues, i can't tell clients to run it from a server...

The big idea after it, is that i need the app to check for new files in the server, if there are any, to download them.
Also, i want the app to be able to access those downloaded files when it is offline as well.

I guess using only phonegap in ios will solve this, but i still need it to work on windows desktop as well.

Comment: you can do a "cordova platform add desktop" on your project

Comment: Desktop platform is used to target Desktop browser, like Chrome for example, not to create a desktop app. http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps

Comment: so? you run the app through chrome, but he said "and i don't mind it to be as normal offline website ( via index.html, not an exe )", so I think it should fit his needs

Comment: jcesarmobile But then i have the security issue, i can't access files withour server side.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap released PhoneGap Desktop 
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/11/phonegap-desktop-app-beta/

I think this is what you are looking for!

Comment: no, phonegap desktop app is an app to create cordova projects from there instead of using the CLI